# How to get directory path to a batch file when right click in inside folder background?

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, registry

**file.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\xfiles]
@="文件命名操作(&A)"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\xfiles\command]
@="cmd.exe /c C:\\bat\\file.bat %1 \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\xfiles]
@="文件命名操作(&A)"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\xfiles\command]
@="cmd.exe /c C:\\bat\\file-bg.bat %cd% \"%V\""
```

**file.bat**

```
@echo off
set HandleDir=%1
if "%HandleDir%"=="" exit /b
echo %HandleDir%
rem ...
```

**file-bg.bat**

```
@echo off
set HandleDir=%cd%
if "%HandleDir%"=="" exit /b
echo %HandleDir%
rem ...
```

`%1`,
Directory\shell , get directory path on the directory icon,

`%cd%`,
Directory\Background, get directory path at inside folder background.

Comment: Try with `set "HandleDir=%~1"` to avoid trouble with white-spaces or special characters...

Comment: `@="cmd.exe /c C:\\bat\\file-bg.bat %cd% \"%V\""`